# $G \cong \mathbb{Z}_{p^{n_1}}\times \dots \mathbb{Z}_{p^{n_k}}$. If $p=2$ and $n_1>n_2$, prove that $L(G)\cong \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $G \cong \mathbb{Z}_{p^{n_1}}\times \dots \mathbb{Z}_{p^{n_k}}$ be a finite abelian $p$-group, in which $n_1\geq \dots \geq n_k$.
Define $$L(G)=\{g\in G \;|\;\alpha(g)=g\; ,\forall \alpha\in Aut(G)\}$$
If $p=2$ and $n_1>n_2$, prove that $L(G)\cong \mathbb{Z}_2$.

In doing this question the main problem I faced is I can't get a general formula for every automorphism of $G$. I tried with $G\cong\mathbb{Z}_8\times \mathbb{Z}_4$. But there are too many automorphisms of $G$ and I can't get a general formula which includes all the automorphisms. And in this case I also can't choose a particular automorphism such that $L(G)\cong \mathbb{Z}_2$.

For example: $G\cong \mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_2=\{1,a,a^2.a^3\}\times \{1,b\}$
For this case I find all the possible automorphisms of $G$ which are $$\alpha(a^i,b^j)=(a^i,b^j)\\ \alpha(a^i,b^j)=(a^{3i},b^j),\\ \alpha(a^i,b^j)=(a^i,b^{i+j})\\ \alpha(a^i,b^j)=(a^{3i},b^{i+j}),\\
\alpha(a^i,b^j)=\alpha(a^{i+j},b^j),\\ \alpha(a^i,b^j)=(a^{i+3j},b^j)\\
\alpha(a^i,b^j)=\alpha(a^{i+j},b^i),\\ \alpha(a^i,b^j)=(a^{3i+j},b^i)
$$
Then I list down all the images of each automorphisms and compare to get the $L(G)=\{(1,1),(a^2,1)\}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: The non-zero element of $L(G)$ is $g=(2^{n_1-1},0,0,\dots,0)$.

Why must this element be fixed by all automorphism? (This is where you use that $n_1>n_2$.)

For any other non-zero element, find an automorphism that fails to fix it. You don't need to pick a "particular automophism." For any $h\in G$ other than $0,g$, you need to find an automorphism. It doesn't have to be the same automorphism for each $h$.

Let $h_i$ be the standard basis: $h_1=(1,0,0,\dots,0), h_2=(0,1,0,\dots,0),\dots, h_k=(0,0,\dots,0,1)$.

For $i>1$, define $\alpha_i$ which sends $h_j\mapsto h_j$ for $j\neq i$ and $h_i\mapsto h_i+2^{n_1-n_i}h_1$.  This fails to fix $(g_j)$ when $g_k\neq 0$.

So now you need to only check the elements of the type $ah_1$. Picking an automorphism which sends $h_1\mapsto -h_1$ and $h_i\mapsto h_i$ for $i>0$ only fixes $ah_i$ if $ah_i=-ah_i$, or if $2a=0$. That leaves two elements that are not fixed.

The case $\mathbb Z_4\oplus \mathbb Z_2$ is instructive.

Define $\alpha_2(a,b)=(a+2b,b)$. This fails to fix any element $(a,1)$.

Define $\alpha_1(a,b)=(-a,b)$. The $\alpha_1$ fails to fix any element where $a\neq 0$ and $a\neq 2$.

So the only elements of $\mathbb Z_4\oplus\mathbb Z_2$ that are fixed by $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ are $(0,0)$ and $(2,0)$.

Now you just need to show that $(2,0)\in L(G)$ and you are done.

Comment: I had proved for the case $\mathbb{Z}_4\times \mathbb{Z_2}$ which is updated above. But for the general case, I cannot list all the automorphisms since they are too many possibilities and I cannot get a general formula for them. So your suggestion is for every element $g \not \in L(G)$, find an automorphism which shows that $\alpha(g)\neq g$?

Comment: You don't need to list all automorphisms, you need to pick, for each $h\notin G\setminus L(G)$, a single automorphism that doesn't fix $h$. See my extended answer to see how that is done. You only actually need to look at $k$ automorphisms...

Comment: I am still confused with your statement that "For $i>1$, define $\alpha_i$ which sends $h_j\mapsto h_j$ for $j\neq i$ and $h_i\mapsto h_i+2^{n_1-n_i}h_1$.  This fails to fix $(g_j)$ when $g_k\neq 0$.". If following this way, $\alpha_2(a,b)$ should be $(a,b+2a)$ isn't it? And I found that this function is not 1-1.

Comment: No, $(a,b)=ah_1+bh_2$ so $ah_1\mapsto ah_1$ and $bh_2\mapsto b(h_2+2h_1)$ so $(a,b)\mapsto (a+2b)h_1+bh_2$. @AlanWang